# Query Issues! Assistance requested

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

Not sure what is wrong with my query, but I can't get it to return any results. I'm using the 2012 version of **Northwind** as far as I know, and I am trying to get the ProductID, ProductName, Supplier Name, and Quantity purchased for each customer, whose value I am retrieving from a DropDownList as the parameter p1.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT Products.ProductID,
       Products.ProductName,
       Suppliers.CompanyName,
       [Order Details].Quantity
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
INNER JOIN [Order Details] ON Orders.OrderID = [Order Details].OrderID
INNER JOIN Products ON [Order Details].ProductID = Products.ProductID
INNER JOIN Suppliers ON Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.SupplierID
WHERE (Orders.CustomerID = @p1);
```

If anyone can figure out the issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: you forgot to tell us what is The Issue

Comment: I'm not getting any results back, and I've run queries to check that there are orders placed under a few test cases. @Mureinik

Comment: My query doesn't return any results @Plutonix

Comment: @MicroBM have you ran the query directly in `SQL` and if so what was the results. Also you did not post how you are calling this query/ stored procedure and this would be very helpful so we can further help you.

Comment: Try without the `WHERE` clause. If it works you know you are setting the `@p1` parameter incorrectly or to a value you did not expect.

Answer (score 0):

When i run your query without the parameter the result is just fine, so we're safe to say there is something wrong with your input. 
when i run it like this there is also no problem, didnt you forget something like the DECLARE?

```
DECLARE @p1 NVARCHAR(30)    
SET @p1 = 'VINET'
```

Cheers!

Comment: I'm getting the parameter value from a dropdownlist. The query is part of an ASP.NET application